# Block the "cms" tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-blacklist-request

Questions migrated from other SE sites are sometimes tagged [cms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cms). As drupal.SE is about Drupal, which a CMS, that tag should be blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added [cms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cms) to the blacklist.

Comment: Thank you.